# System Requirements for running CodeDom

Tags: c#, codedom, system-requirements

I know that C# applications will require the .Net framework to execute on any given machine. However, I am curious, in order for CodeDom to work properly must Visual Studio also be installed on the computer the application is being run? I only ask because doesn't CodeDom use a file that is part of the VS installation when producing files?

If you know of any other system requirements I would appreciate hearing about them.

Comment: “C# applications in general require .Net 2.0” C# applications written for .Net 2.0 do. C# applications written for different versions of the framework obviously require different versions of the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using CodeDOM doesn't require Visual Studio to be installed. It works fine without it.

And compiling code by yourself doesn't require VS either. All you need is the [C# compiler – csc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx). And that is part of the .Net installation. When compiling source code to an assembly, CodeDOM actually invokes csc.exe.